# Kohana controller URI basics

Tags: php, url-routing, kohana

Re: Kohana v2.3.4.

Do I have to create a new controller for every URL which uses `segment 2`? In other words, if I want my URLs to be:

- www.example.com/foo
- www.example.com/bar

... do I need to create a unique controller for `foo` and a unique controller for `bar`? I'd like to create just one controller, if possible.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to avoid redirection at all costs, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to have a controller for every `segment 2` , but if you only want a "foo" controller than you should use routing.

Answer (score 3):

From here: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/routing

It looks like you can do:

```
$config['foo'] = 'controller/action'; // access at /foo
$config['bar'] = 'controller/action'; // access at /bar
```

Comment: If I "solved" the problem, it should be the checked answer, no?

Comment: I'd vote Jeff down, if I could. This is not fair. Garrett should get the check mark. His solution is dated before MarocBarosa's.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your router to redirect bar to foo. Don't forget to send http/302, in order to not confusing crawlers. Google doesn't like if more url's point to the same resource.

Comment: So, without redirection, you're saying "Yes, you do have to create multiple controllers?" Bummer.